# WordPress subdirectory multisite nginx configuration in Microsoft Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx

I have a Microsoft Azure application running WordPress.

**Stack:**

- WordPress 6.2.2 with a multisite subdirectory network

  - While it is a subdirectory network, all sites in the network share the same folders, e.g. there is no `/da/` folder (besides from `/uploads/` for media)
- PHP 8.2.5
- Microsoft Azure as hosting platform
- Linux
- Nginx

I've used this guide: [How to setup Multisite in WordPress on Azure App Service](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-setup-multisite-in-wordpress-on-azure-app-service/ba-p/3791071), and I've set up the multisite network.

I've also added the necessary configurations in `wp-config.php`.

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.net' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

**Main site**: example.com
**Subsite**: example.com/da

The main site is working fine, but the subsite is not. It's not a blank page, there are some elements being displayed, but nothing WordPress-related is working:
[image]

I cannot access `example.com/da/wp-admin/`, as I am redirected to the 404 page.
When I go to e.g. `example.com/da/wp-content/` it says "File not found", when it should just show a blank page if WordPress was working correctly.

From previous experiences with Apache / using a `.htaccess`-file to configure a multisite network setup, I'm thinking it's an `nginx` configuration issue.

**My current configuration file:** (Microsoft Azure default `nginx` file with modifications made to server name + directory path)

```html
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
    #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name example.net www.example.net example.net/da www.example.net/da;
    ## Your only path reference.
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /home/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            root /home/;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /home/;
        }
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html
    sendfile off;
    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }                                                                                                                                             
                                       
    if ($query_string != "") {                                                                
        set $skip_cache 1;                                                  
    }                                        
                                                                            
    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;                                                   
    }                                                   
                                                                             
    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters                        
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;                                                          
    }                                                                               
                                                                             
    # Don't cache WooCommerce URLs                                
    # Cart widgets are still a problem: https://github.com/emcniece/docker-wordpress/issues/3                     
    if ($request_uri ~* "/(cart|checkout|my-account)/*$") {                         
        set $skip_cache 1;             
    }                                                                                     
                                              
    location / {                                                                             
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.                      
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;                                                 
    }                                                                        
                                                                                          
    location ~* \.php$ {                                                     
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini                               
        include fastcgi.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;                                                     
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;                                                      
        fastcgi_pass php;                               
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;                                                            
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;                                                       
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;                                                           
        fastcgi_cache off;                                                                
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;                                                                                  
    }                                                                                     
                                                                                                                  
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {                                             
        expires max;                          
        log_not_found off;                                                                   
    }                                                             
}
```

### What I've tried

- Made many, many different configurations to the nginx file inside `/home/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` by creating a startup script that copies the contents of another file and inserts it into the `default.conf` file, [following this guide](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/updating-nginx-default-configurations-on-azure-app-services/ba-p/3710146). I also made sure to run this startup script inside Microsoft Azure > Configuration.
- Made the same configurations to `/home/site/wwwroot/nginx.conf`, although I don't think this is the right file for `nginx` configurations?
- Made configurations to `/home/site/wwwroot/web.config` as suggested by ChatGPT, although I don't think this is correct either?
- Tried following [WordPress' `nginx` rules article](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/#wordpress-multisite-subdirectory-rules) and implementing them in my `default.conf` file (I might not have done this correctly though)
- Tried cloning the main site as a new subsite + creating a new, blank subsite, the issue persists on both subsites

Any type of information that could help me the slighest get to the bottom of the issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Do I get it right, that one page should run on `example.net` and the other one with complete other content&design - in fact an other wordpress instance - should run on `example.net/da`? Listening to best practice it would be better to have a subdomain for the second website like `da.example.net`. Have you thought about that, and is there a reason you dont want this? Else we should target this approach with further help.

Comment: Same for phpmyadmin. It's much better to have a root for an application which is seperated from other content. Imagine you create a blog post about phpmyadmin on you example website. You wont be able to make it accessible unter example.net/phpmyadmin, because you have a second application in the root of your wordpress application. It's not really good, that wordpress then has no full control about its "space", but if there is a specific reason for that you can still do it that way. Subdomains would still be recommended.

Comment: Hello @Geilmaker, it is running on the exact same WordPress instance, and each site shares the same root directory (`/wwwroot/wp-content` e.g.). The content on the site is identical, aside from texts, which are translated to another language. I can ask the client if they are willing to change it to a subdomain website instead, but I'd prefer to keep it to `example.net/da` for now.

Comment: Ok, im not completly into multisite and you dont need to explain it to me if it is too hard. But if its the same wordpress instance - why would you like to access the `/da/wp-admin` uri, if the admin login for the instance is under `/wp-admin`?

Comment: Honestly your link https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/#wordpress-multisite-subdirectory-rules looks pretty promising. You mentioned you might have done something wrong. Can you just move your current configuration to another place (where its not read by nginx, so you dont have to delete it or comment every line) and create the file from the link, with replaced `server_name` and `root` and change the `alias` inside the `location ^~ /blogs.dir`? At least something else should happen, maybe you can describe whats happening with that config.

Comment: I don't want to access any specific directory/folder, the problem is that my subsite(s) are not working, anything WP related seems to be broken on the subsite(s). That's why I'm convinced it's an `nginx` configuration issue, I've seen the same error on sites with `apache` where the configuration was wrong in `.htaccess`.

Comment: I have tried implementing the conf file in the article I've linked to but I still had the same issue. The site didn't crash, but nothing changed. What I just don't understand is why this article is including `/wp-content/blogs.dir`, from what I can tell, this file has not been used since WordPress 3.5. The documentation in the article is not very descriptive. @Geilmaker

Comment: Okay, im gonna have a more detailed look at the topic. I'll do some tests using docker. Would you have the possibility to use docker too, or you can't/don't want?

Comment: Okay... Using docker everything works fine, even with nginx. The reason thatfore is, that the wordpress docker image already has an apache webserver sitting in front and nginx is just proxying the requests to the given apache webserver. If you want a clean and simple solution that might be a way to go.

Comment: Hey @Geilmaker, we ended up doing something completely different, but thank you for taking your time to help me out :) much appreciated.